# jQuery Tools Tabs not displaying in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, html, tabs, jquery-tools

It might be a long shot posting this question here but we will see. I have created simple tabs using jQuery tools. The only thing i think i have changed is that instead of setting all div elements within the main panes div to `display:none` only divs with a specific class are set to display:none, this has allowed me to put divs within the tab content.

It all works fine except in IE7 (and possibly lower) where none of the tabs content displays and clicking on the tabs does nothing. An example below:

[http://mtsoc.enfotext.com/past-shows/2005-chess](http://mtsoc.enfotext.com/past-shows/2005-chess/)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't like the trailing comma:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.tabs_panes > div", {
    // enable the history feature
    history: true,
});
```

Remove it and it should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a trailing comma in an object on line 169. This shouldn't be there - I'm not sure if it fixes your problem, but IE is throwing an error on it.